During a remodel lost power to ceiling fans
During a remodel all receptacles and switches were replaced. The ceiling fan in the living room and the ceiling fan in the back bedroom lost power. I rechecked all outlets and switches; all checked out good. Both fans worked at some point; one fan was taken down and put back, now I have no power to either fan. I can pull power from another source and power returns to both areas. I've checked all plugs and switches, they all have power coming in and the ones that have power have power going out. I need some help determining where my short is.

When you pulled that fan down, you lost or broke a wire. Take it down again and check.

During the remodel, were any nails/screws put in the walls/ceiling?  In replacing the receptacles/switches, did you use the screws or the back push in connections?

Are you aware that punctuation is a thing? Your question is unnecessarily difficult to read and parse without any.

Note that if it was a short, you would probably blow the circuit breaker. Instead, you have lost power. This could be because a connector came loose, or somebody cut through a cable.
